# What is the difference between RestClient::Request.execute and RestClient.post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest-client

I made a post request with `RestClient::Request.execute`, which works, but sometimes it ended with a `422`(Unprocessable Entity).

Afterwards I tried out `RestClient.post` which didn´t gave me the `422` and worked all the time like a charm.

What is the difference between the two Calls?

I know that with `RestClient::Request` there are more possibilities for using parameters than with `RestClient.post`. I do not understand why i get a `422` with one method and not with the other.

Here I used json:

```
response = RestClient::Request.execute(
        :method => :post,
        :url =>  'http://localhost:3000',
        :timeout => 30,
        :open_timeout => 2,
        :payload => payload.to_json,
        :headers => {
            :content_type => :json,
            :accept => :json
        }
    )
```

vs.

```
response = RestClient.post('http://localhost:3000',
          :param1 => 'abc',
          :param2 => "def")
```

Comment: Can you please post examples for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same - `RestClient.post` is a syntax sugar for `execute`, see restclient's sources, [restclient.rb](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient.rb#L69):

```
def self.post(url, payload, headers={}, &block)
    Request.execute(:method => :post,
       :url => url,
       :payload => payload,
       :headers => headers, &block)
end
```

The 422 is caused by something else